# concatenate vector of strings into a single string - for each row in df

Tags: r, stringr

This may be an easy one but I could not find a solution.
I have a df of strings, for example:

```
data <- data.frame(x1 = c("abc", "", "de"), 
                   x2 = c("fghi", "j", "kl"), 
                   x3 = c("m", "", ""))
> data                                       
  x1   x2  x3
1 abc      de
2 fghi j   kl
3 m
```

I want to concatenate each row into a single string, so that the output only has one column:

```
> data
  x1
1 abc de
2 fghi j kl
3 m
```

I tried

```
apply(data, 2, paste)
```

but it doesn't work, and neither does any variation of stringr::str_c.
any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close to the right code, just add collapse and work on rows with margin=1:

```
apply(data, 1, paste,collapse=" ")
[1] "abc fghi m" " j "        "de kl "
```

from documentation

> collapse   an optional character string to separate the results.

To integrate the output in your dataset:

```
data$pasted<-apply(data, 1, paste,collapse=" ")
> data
   x1   x2 x3     pasted
1 abc fghi  m abc fghi m
2        j            j 
3  de   kl        de kl
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using `paste`, with `sep = " "` :

```
data$new_col <- paste(data$x1, data$x2, data$x3, sep = " ")
```

Or

```
require(stringr)
data <- within(data,  new_col <- paste(x1, x2, x3, sep=" ")
```

Or

```
data$new_col <- as.character(interaction(data,sep=" "))
```

*`interaction` returns a `factor` that's why i convert to `as.character`*

All 3 ways will get you:

```
   x1   x2 x3    new_col
1 abc fghi  m abc fghi m
2        j            j 
3  de   kl        de kl
```

Answer (score 1):

With the additon of `dplyr`, one way to use `str_c()` could be:

```
data %>%
 rowwise() %>%
 transmute(x1 = str_c(c_across(everything()), collapse = " "))

  x1          
  <chr>       
1 "abc fghi m"
2 " j "       
3 "de kl "
```